# Reducing a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Let $\mathbf F$ be a system of 1st order differential equations in $n>3$ variables
$$\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$$
$$\frac{d\mathbf{u}}{dt} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})$$

such that $\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial t} = 0$.

We've referenced $\mathbf{u} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Let's also name a function $\mathbf{v} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$.

$\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ have multiple elements, each expressible as an independent function of $t$. Call the 0th elements $\mathrm{u}_0$ and $\mathrm{v}_0$.

Is it always possible to find a system $\mathbf G$ in three variables $$\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} = \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{v})$$
such that $\frac{\partial\mathbf{G}}{\partial t} = 0$ and $\mathrm{u}_0 = \mathrm{v}_0$?

To keep things simple you may assume $\mathbf{F}$ is smooth. Is the answer very different if it's merely continuous?

Is there a more succinct way to ask this question?

Comment: I guess you can do so if the higher-dimensional equation "doesn't need" the additional states. I guess that what you are looking for is not generally true (unless you impose additional conditions on $\mathbf{F}$). Just a thought:  let $\mathbf{v}(t) = \mathbf{C}\mathbf{u}(t)$, where $\mathbf{C}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times n}$ and and notice that $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\mathbf{C}'\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})$; can you write $\mathbf{u}(t)=\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{v}(t)$?

Comment: Hm, I don't see the significance of that. (BTW, wouldn't we have $\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} = \mathbf{C}'\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{C\,F}(\mathbf{u})$? And what does $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$ mean unless $\mathbf{C}$ is square?)

Comment: It's just a thought... $\mathbf{C}$ is a rectangular matrix and $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$ is the (multivalued) inverse mapping, so the dynamics is then described by a differential inclusion, however, you can pick a Lipschitz-continuous selection, say $c\in\mathbf{C}^{-1}$. Also, it is $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}(t)}{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{Cu}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\mathbf{C}'\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{u} (t) }{\mathrm{d}t}=\mathbf{C}'\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})\in\mathbf{C}'\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{v})$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial t}$ when $\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Perhaps I should have just said "$\mathbf{F}$ is not a function of $t$". That's how $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial t} = 0.$

Comment: But F is never a function of t...

Comment: I was just making it extra clear because I thought some people might miss the very point you're understanding: that if we have $\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{u} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, all degrees of freedom in $\mathbf{F}$ are "accounted for" -- there's no "room" for $\mathbf{F}$ to be a function of $t$.

Comment: Besides, we also have $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial q} = 0$, $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \aleph} = 0$, $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial ?}=0$, etc., because wrt every other variable in the universe, $\mathbf{F}$ is constant.